# In state_machine, how to set next state based on the outcome of running an event?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, state-machine

I am using Aaron Pfeifer's [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) gem in my Rails3 app -- it's (still) nifty.

I have a event whose outcome isn't known until it has been processed, and I would like to set the following state based on the outcome.  The 'obvious' approach shown here doesn't work: it raises an `ArgumentError: :picked_many is not a known state value` error.

What's the right way to set the state based on the outcome of an event?  (Or am I just thinking about this wrong?)

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base 
  state_machine :initial => :top do 
    event :pickanumber do
      transition any => any
    end 
    state :picked_zero 
    state :picked_one 
    state :picked_many 
  end 
  def pickanumber(n) 
    self.state = case n 
                 when 0 then :picked_zero 
                 when 1 then :picked_one 
                 else :picked_many 
                 end 
    super
  end 
end
```

and a sample run:

```
> m = MyModel.create 
=> #<MyModel id: 26, state: "top", ...>
> m.pickanumber(2) 
ArgumentError: :picked_many is not a known state value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State is internally stored as a string and not symbol.

This should work...

```
def pickanumber(n)
    self.state = case n
                 when 0 then "picked_zero"
                 when 1 then "picked_one"
                 else "picked_many"
                 end
    super
end
```

Comment: Why a String and not a Symbol? Seems like the kind of thing the Symbol construct was designed for--an immutable string-like label.

Comment: Omygoshyouareright -- @dexter's version works.  I'm with @Damien -- it just seems odd that `state :picked_one` works with a symbol but `self.state = "picked_one"` requires a string.  I'll ping the author...

Comment: @fearless_fool: The API page for the state_machine libary seems to remove a lot of the mystery: http://rdoc.info/github/pluginaweek/state_machine/master/frames

Comment: @Damien: Agreed -- the documentation is excellent -- but it doesn't remove the mystery of the OP!  :)